# Is NP in NP/Poly?

Tags: turing-machines, np, nondeterminism, circuits, simulation

The answer is yes, NP/poly is defined as the class of problems solvable in polynomial time by a non-deterministic Turing machine that has access to a polynomial-bounded advice function--the advice function only adds power; however, I'm having a hard time understanding NP/poly's containment of NP from the angle of the definition below of NP/poly:

A nondeterministic circuit has two inputs x,y. The circuit C accepts x iff there exists y such that C(x,y) = 1. The size of the circuit is measured as a function of |x|. **NP/poly** is the set of languages decided by polynomial size non-deterministic circuits.

A nondeterministic Turing machine has two inputs w,c. A verifier V accepts w iff there exists a certificate c such that V(w,c) = 1. The length of computation is measured as a function of |w|. **NP** is the set of languages decided by a nondeterministic Turing machine that runs in polynomial time.

From the verifier angle, for a couple reasons it is hard to see how a single circuit of poly size could implement a verifier for an NP problem for all the words of a given length.

1. For example. let's say an NP language has an exponential number of yes instances of a given length all with various certificates. Let's say we consider those certificates that are descriptions of the accepting branches of a non-deterministic Turing machine that correctly decide each w of the given length--how could a **single** poly size circuit simulate all these (possibly exponential number of) c's (solution paths) on their respective w's to see if the verifier works?
2. A circuit can only have a single size input and for each size of input there is only one circuit in the circuit family; yet, for a given word w of length b there are an infinte number of c's that are poly|w| that are potential certificates--how can the single circuit for inputs of length b accept on all the different certificates for the w's of length b when their lengths are variable?

Looking for some help on how I'm thinking about this wrong, thank you!

Comment: The last paragraph is hard to understand. Please try to reformat it (at least split this into bullet list: one item per issue). `there are an infinte number of c's that are poly|w| that are potential certificates for w's of length b--how can a single circuit ... accept on all the different certificates for the w's` - you don't care about **all** of them. It suffices to know that there exists a certificate with size polynomial of input size. For each $x$. there exists a certificate of size $p(|x|)$: the input layer of the circuit will have size $|x| + p(|x|)$. This way, it'll include some cert.

Comment: @Dmitry cleaned it up a bit--thank you--addressing your comment in relation to the question: does that mean there is a poly size circuit for every length of word
+certificate pair? If so, some of those circuits might need to accept ||+(||) as well as another |y|+(|y|) if |y|+(|y|)=||+(||). Cases like this seem like they could present a problem, no? How can you predict when this is going to happen?

Comment: The verifier $V$ is a *deterministic* Turing machine. There is only one computation branch.

Comment: By padding witnesses, you can assume that their size only depends on the input size.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus in the case where the certificate is a description of a solution path and there are two |y|+(|y|) if |y|+(|y|)=||+(||) or more arguments of same length for the circuit--then a single circuit would need to walk multiple (possibly exponential) number of solution paths to verify a bunch of w's whose w + c all happen to line up with that length, could there not be a case like this?

Comment: No. You have a different circuit for each $|x|$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus right, but could there not be a situation where certificate + word and anther certificate + word combination happen to fall on the same length and therefor the same circuit needs to handle both of these -- and there could be even more (an exponential number could line up this way).

Comment: No. You have a difference circuit for each $|x|$. It doesn't matter if this sort of coincidence happens.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I'm referring to Dimitry's comment "the input layer of the circuit will have size  ||+(||)" if you have multiple certificate, word combinations lining up all with same length -- then the same circuit would need to handle all of them (because as you said one circuit for each input size --there could be a case where an exponential number of these line up and in this case you would still need to guarantee a poly size circuit exists that can handle this unfortunate coincidence

Comment: I really don't follow. The circuit gets $x$ and $y$, and simulates the deterministic polytime Turing machine on $x$ and $y$. You can do this with a polynomial size circuit.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus the circuit accepts arguments of size |certificate| + |word| -- there could be multiple different |certificate| + |word| combos that have the same length--then a single circuit would  need to simulate multiple polytime Turing machine paths -- and you could have up to 2^n word, certificate combinations line up this way -- if this happens then a single poly size circuit needs to carry the burden of simulating an exponential number of different poly time machines (certificates) on all the different words those solution paths are certificates for.

Comment: There could be multiple combinations having the same length, but it makes absolutely no difference, since you have a different circuit for each $|x|$. The circuit *knows* $|x|$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus sometimes the certificate y for a word x is itself a description of the solution path -- in the case for such certificates you verify the word x by essentially simulating y on (x) -- if an exponential number of these line up and fall on one circuit -- dont see how it can be guaranteed to only be poly size when it needs to handle all these diff simulations

Comment: I'm really not sure how to carry this point across more clearly: you have a sequence of circuits $c_1,c_2,\ldots$, where $c_n$ gets two inputs: $x$ of size $n$, and $y$ of size $p(n)$, where $p$ is some polynomially bounded function.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the certificate $y$ is. We don't care. All we need to know is that there is a polytime deterministic Turing machines that can compute $C(x,y)$.

Comment: Do you know how to translate a Turing machine to a circuit? This is essentially Cook's theorem.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus ok, i get it from the view of your translation--from the angle before I was just worried about a single circuit being able to handle some extreme case where  |y|+(|y|)=|x|+(|x|)=|z|+(|z|)=|v|+(|v|)=... an exponential number of valid certificate word combos fall on the same length--and those p(v), p(y)... are descriptions of solution paths--now a single circuit needs to be able to simulate an exponential number of solution paths p(y) on on all those words y they are solution paths for, and such a circuit still needs to be max poly size--this seemed impossible to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A language $L$ is in $\mathsf{NP}$ if there exists a polynomial $p$ and a deterministic Turing machine $T$, running in polynomial time, such that:

> $x \in L$ if and only if there exists $y$ of length $p(|x|)$ such that $T(x,y) = 1$.

Usually we assume that $|y| \leq p(|x|)$, but we can get this version using a simple padding argument, which slightly increases $p$. For example, we could encode $y$ as follows: $0^{p(|x|)-|y|}1y$. This always has length $p(|x|)+1$. (We also obtain a new witness $0^{p(|x|)+1}$ which corresponds to no $y$, which $T$ can just immediately reject.)

For every $n$, we can construct a polynomial size circuit $C_n$ on $n + p(n)$ inputs such that for every $x$ of length $n$ and $y$ of length $p(n)$, we have $C_n(x,y) = T(x,y)$. A similar construction appears in Cook's theorem, for example. This shows that $\mathsf{NP} \subseteq \mathsf{NP/{poly}}$.